# Mapbox zoom level per country

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Hi i'm trying to find a way to show a country fully by country code in Mapbox.

I'm using [country-iso-to-coordinates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-iso-to-coordinates) to get the coordinates by country-iso code

For example userCountry = "FR" (France) results in 2.213749, 46.227638 as center points. This works, but i'd also like to have the zoom level fitting the country's boundaries. France for example looks perfect at zoom level 4.3, while big countries like USA or China need zoom level of ~2.2.

```
data() {
    return {
        accessToken: 'xxxxx',
        mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/psteger/cl0y1upof001f16sxix3n00oe',
        center: [10, 51],
        zoom: 4.3,
        minZoom: 2.2,
        maxZoom: 14,
        markers: [],
        params: {
            access_token: 'xxxxx',
            country: 'de',
            language: 'en'
        }
    }
},
mounted() {
    const coordinates = IsoToLatLong[this.userCountry];
    this.center = [coordinates.coordinate[1], coordinates.coordinate[0]]
},
```

How can i find a working zoom level that shows the whole country without manually trying and writing a list for each single country? Is there a package with ratios of each country so i could calculate the zoom levels or can mapbox's API set a zoom level by a country's borders?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Focusing on "zoom level" is usually the wrong approach, because it depends on device size. The right zoom level to see all of France on 2000 pixel wide desktop browser window will be different from the right zoom level for a phone. Use bounding boxes, as per tao below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [country-bounding-boxes](https://github.com/sandstrom/country-bounding-boxes) which would allow you the following method:

```
import boundingBoxes from 'country-bounding-boxes/bounding-boxes.json';

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    zoomToCountry(isoCode) {
      this.map.fitBounds(boundingBoxes[isoCode][1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a pretty basic [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-panini-w2zr46?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: Thank you for that very nice solution! Got it to work and it's really elegant how it includes the flight to the selected country.